# Include folders with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, include, apache2, server-side-includes

Let's say a user goes to the address domain.com/test.php

Is it possible some how if the file test.php don't exist to include an other file located elsewhere on the server?

Im thinking something like this if my webroot is located at /home/user/www/:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [NC,OR]
INCLUDE: /VAR/OTHERDIR/test.php
```

EDIT: /VAR/OTHERDIR/ Is a Local path

And if the file doesn't exist in the other folder first then throw E:404.

Would appreciate help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^test.php$ /other/dir/test.php [L]
```

If the file test.php exists on your server it will be shown. If it does not exists, there will be a redirect to /other/dir/test.php. If this file does not exists, a 404 error will be shown.

Comment: /other/dir/ is a local path, not a URL. The example from above doesn't work for me i'm afraid.

Comment: Then you can simply rewrite to another PHP file, which tries to include the local file and displays a 404 error if the local file does not exists.

Comment: That worked only on PHP files. I wan't it to work on every file... I solved part of my problem using a symlink to /other/dir/. But now i can't put other files in.

Comment: You can display PHP files with `include`, but for other filetypes you can use the functions `readfile()` or `file_get_contents()`.